# how to display image from a column in sqlite database

Tags: image, sqlite, tkinter

i am developing a dictionary that display meaning and image of a word at the same time when the word is being searched.I want to display image from a column on a table in sqlite database but it is giving me error

```
def search(event=''):
   conn = sqlite3.connect('G_DICTION.db')
   cur = conn.cursor()
   tex.delete(1.0, "end")
   data = v.get()
   cur.execute("SELECT Meaning, Image FROM DICTION WHERE Words= ?", (data,))
   var = cur.fetchone()
   if var:
       tex.insert("end", var[0])  # accessing the meaning
   else:
       messagebox.showinfo("Dic", "Word not found")
   #####################################
   img_path = var[1]                            # accessing the path to the image
   image_object = tk.PhotoImage(img_path)  # here I'm not using PIL, but tkinter PhotoImage
   ImageLabel.config(image=image_object)
   ImageLabel.image = image_object    

frame = tk.Frame(dictWin)
frame.place(x=50, y=395)
ImageLabel = tk.Label(frame, font=("calibra", 9), bg="white")
ImageLabel.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=65, pady=20)
```

this is the error below;

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Temmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, 
in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Temmy\.PyCharmEdu2019.1\config\scratches\newdatba.py", line 23, in search
    ImageLabel.config(image=image_object)
NameError: name 'ImageLabel' is not defined
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Temmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, 
in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Temmy\.PyCharmEdu2019.1\config\scratches\newdatba.py", line 23, in search
     ImageLabel.config(image=image_object)
NameError: name 'ImageLabel' is not defined
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  How do you trigger `search()` function?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by trigger search(). please explain,

Comment: That means where and how the `search()` function be called.  Also please update your code to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because there are many missing parts.

Comment: okay."Butt = ttk.Button(dictWin, width=10, command=search,text="Search").place(x=370, y=21)". the problem has been solved because i used ImageLabe1 instead of ImageLabel. but another error has comes up;

Comment: okay."Butt = ttk.Button(dictWin, width=10, command=search,text="Search").place(x=370, y=21)". the problem has been solved because i used ImageLabe1 instead of ImageLabel. but another error has comes up;